# Keep subtracting until i reach a number less than 24

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

im new to python or programming in general so this might be simple but im stuck!
It would be great if anyone could help me! ^^

I want to be able to do a piece of code that does this:

> takes 2 inputs: x and y

```
x = float(input("Hours(00 to 24):\n"))

y = float(input("Hours until flight:\n"))
```

> then i want to add them together so that the value is between 00:00
>   and 24:00

```
    i = (x+y)

  if i < float(24):

    print ("Your plane leaves at:",i)

  elif i > float(24):

 do something that keeps the result always less than 24:00h so that even if its 14:00h and your flight is in 51 hours the result isnt 65:00h but 17:00h (dont need the 2 days that went by, just the hour)
```

Hope you can understand :/

Thanks

Comment: modulus divison

Comment: You should post a compiling code with what you tried and explain what didn't work there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the modulus function. This finds the remainder when dividing by the specified number. In this case, if the time was 25 hours, you would be left with 1. Or if the time was 30 hours for example, you would be left with six.

To implement this you would do: `print("Your plane leaves at: ", i % 24)`

Note that if the time is a multiple of 24 though, it will print 0.

Comment: 'if i < float(24):
    print ("O seu aviao parte ás",i)
elif i > float(24):
    a = i % 24
    print ("O teu aviao parte ás",a)
elif y == float(24):
    print (x)
'
because if time until flight is 24 its a hole day so it the same hour but a day later (but here days dont matter)

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(x,y):  # x and y as defined by OP
    i = x + y  # sets i as defined by OP
    if i < 24.0  # does the bit that OP asked for if i<24
        print("Your phone leaves at:", i)
    elif i > 24.0  # does the other bit op asked for
        i = i % 24.0  # get the remainder of dividing i by 24
        print("Your phone leaves at:", i)  #  prints the result of the last one
```

should do it, not tested.

Main part you need to understand is line 6, using `%` instead of `/` for division gets remainder instead of result of division :)

It's called modulo division

Comment: No need for branches, just apply the modulo operator always.

Comment: I was doing as OP specified. I didn't say it was optimal :)

Comment: Thank you, its done, used your code but changed it :

Comment: x = float(input("Horas atuais(00 até 24):\n"))
y = float(input("Horas que faltam para o voo:\n"))
i = x + y

if i < float(24):
    print ("O seu aviao parte ás",i)
elif i > float(24):
    a = i % 24
    print ("O teu aviao parte ás",a)

Comment: @Raizan What? Sorry, I only understand English, do you mind translating the error you got?

Comment: I think its because i dont know how to put code in the comments, it didnt give me any error

Comment: Ah. What's the problem then? For code, add a backtick before and after your code, for example:  \`code here\`

Comment: `x = float(input("Horas atuais(00 até 24):\n"))
y = float(input("Horas que faltam para o voo:\n"))
i = x + y

if i < float(24):
    print ("O seu aviao parte ás",i)
elif i > float(24):
    a = i % 24
    print ("O teu aviao parte ás",a)
elif y == float(24):
    print (x)`

Comment: it doesnt work lol, nvm its the code is working, thanks for your help :D

Comment: x = float(input("Horas atuais(00 até 24):\n"))
    y = float(input("Horas que faltam para o voo:\n"))
    i = x + y

`if i < float(24):
    print ("O seu aviao parte ás",i)
elif i > float(24):
    a = i % 24
    print ("O teu aviao parte ás",a)
elif y == float(24):
    print (x)`

- This was what i was trying to type... i added the last `elif` so that if the time is a hole day (24hours) if gives the hour that the op gave. i think thats what it does

Comment: nvm, i cant comment right, i posted it as a answer what i was trying to say

Answer (score -1):

```
x = float(input("Horas atuais(00 até 24):\n"))
y = float(input("Horas que faltam para o voo:\n"))
i = x + y

if i < float(24):
    print ("O seu aviao parte ás",i)
elif i > float(24):
    a = i % 24
    print ("O teu aviao parte ás",a)
elif y == float(24):
    print (x)
```

- This was what i was trying to type... i added the last `elif` so that if the time until plane leaves is a hole day (24hours) it gives the hour that the op gave. i think thats what it does

Comment: @Manmeet Gill this was what i was trying to comment... first day in this site... :/

Comment: Ah, okay. Welcome!